# R group by and aggregate - return relative rank within groups using plyr

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate, plyr, dplyr

UPDATE: I have a data frame 'test' that look like this:

```
    session_id  seller_feedback_score
1   1   282470
2   1   275258
3   1   275258
4   1   275258
5   1   37831
6   1   282470
7   1   26
8   1   138351
9   1   321350
10  1   841
11  1   138351
12  1   17263
13  1   282470
14  1   396900
15  1   282470
16  1   282470
17  1   321350
18  1   321350
19  1   321350
20  1   0
21  1   1596
22  7   282505
23  7   275283
24  7   275283
25  7   275283
26  7   37834
27  7   282505
28  7   26
29  7   138359
30  7   321360
```

and a code (using package plyr) that apparently should rank the 'seller_feedback_score' within each group of session_id:

```
 test <- test %>% group_by(session_id) %>% 
  mutate(seller_feedback_score_rank = dense_rank(-seller_feedback_score))
```

however, what is really happening is that R rank the entire data frame together without relating to the groups (session_id's):

```
session_id  seller_feedback_score   seller_feedback_score_rank_2
1   1   282470  5
2   1   275258  7
3   1   275258  7
4   1   275258  7
5   1   37831   11
6   1   282470  5
7   1   26  15
8   1   138351  9
9   1   321350  3
10  1   841 14
11  1   138351  9
12  1   17263   12
13  1   282470  5
14  1   396900  1
15  1   282470  5
16  1   282470  5
17  1   321350  3
18  1   321350  3
19  1   321350  3
20  1   0   16
21  1   1596    13
22  7   282505  4
23  7   275283  6
24  7   275283  6
25  7   275283  6
26  7   37834   10
27  7   282505  4
28  7   26  15
29  7   138359  8
30  7   321360  2
```

I checked this by counting the unique 'seller_feedback_score_rank' values and not surprisingly it equals to the highest rank value. I'd appreciate if someone could reproduce and help. thanks

Comment: same scores get same ranks

Comment: sorry, but it seems that I can't install dplyr because of dependency package lazyeval . When I try to install that dependency, it says that package ‘lazyeval’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Comment: You can update to newest R version and then install

Comment: I opened this again - added new data to reproduce. I also diagnosed that the problem arises from not relating to the group by (session_id) but doing the rank on the entire set

Comment: Seems like you completely removed the original question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(session_id) %>% 
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(-seller_feedback_score))
```

`dense_rank` is "like min_rank, but with no gaps between ranks" so I negated the seller_feedback_score column in order to turn it into something like max_rank (which doesn't exist in dplyr).

If you want the ranks with gaps so that you reach 21 for the lowest in your case, you can use `min_rank` instead of `dense_rank`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(session_id) %>% 
    mutate(rank = min_rank(-seller_feedback_score))
```

Comment: I'm not sure that solution works for me - I do see that a new column was added to my df by the name 'rank', however the values of this column are just the numbers 1:21 (for my example above), ordered, with no evident relation to the seller_feedback_score

Comment: It is quite weird but your solution works for 1 column but not for the other.

Comment: @user3628777, You would need to make this reproducible by providing some data to test it. Without more information I can't verify why it would not work on a different column.. does the column contain positive and negative values? Do you mean it throws an error or are the ranks wrong? ... lots of possibilities

Comment: @user3628777, it's still not clear from the update what you mean that it doesn't work. It's not that obvious to me. Please elaborate.

Comment: It's a little better to use `desc()` instead of `-`

Answer (score 3):

From `data.table 1.9.5` on, `frank()` (for fast rank) function is exported. The interface is similar to `base::rank`, but it implements `dense rank` in addition to all the ranking methods `base::rank` provides, and it also works on a list in addition to vectors. You can install it by following the instructions [**here**](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, 
    rank := frank(-seller_feedback_score, ties.method="dense"), 
by=session_id]
```

As @David points out, perhaps what you want is `rank = "first"` or "min"?? Not sure...

```
setDT(df)[, 
    rank := frank(-seller_feedback_score, ties.method="first"), ## or "min" or "max"
by=session_id]
```

Anyhow, it must be plentiful fast. Here's a benchmark against base R:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(45L)
val = sample(1e4, 1e7, TRUE)
system.time(ans1 <- rank(val, ties.method = "min"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  16.771   0.199  17.035 
system.time(an2 <- frank(val, ties.method = "min"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.532   0.013   0.550 
identical(ans1, ans2) # [1] TRUE
```