# Rank variable by group (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with columns `x1, x2, group` and I would like to generate a new dataframe with an extra column `rank` that indicates the order of `x1` in its group.

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018933/r-data-frame-rank-by-groups-group-by-rank-with-package-dplyr), but the accepted answer does not seem to work anymore.

Until here, it's fine:

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
by_species <- iris %>% 
              arrange(Species, Sepal.Length) %>% 
              group_by(Species)
```

But when I try to get the ranks by group:

```
by_species <- mutate(by_species, rank=row_number())
```

The error is:

> Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") :
>   argument "x" is missing, with no default

**Update**

The problem was some conflict between `dplyr` and `plyr`. To reproduce the error, load both packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
data(iris)
by_species <- iris %>% 
              arrange(Species, Sepal.Length) %>% 
              group_by(Species) %>% 
              mutate(rank=row_number())
# Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
# argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Unloading `plyr` it works as it should:

```
detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)
by_species <- iris %>% 
              arrange(Species, Sepal.Length) %>% 
              group_by(Species) %>% 
              mutate(rank=row_number())

by_species %>% filter(rank <= 3)

##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species  rank
##          (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)     (fctr) (int)
## 1          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa     1
## 2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa     2
## 3          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa     3
## 4          4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor     1
## 5          5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor     2
## 6          5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 versicolor     3
## 7          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica     1
## 8          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0  virginica     2
## 9          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica     3
```

Comment: Are you sure the command `by_species <- mutate(by_species, rank=row_number())` is the one producing the error ?  It works for me and your error refers to the `rank` function, not the `row_number` function that is being used.  Also, if you do use `rank`, you need to provide an argument as in `rank(x)` (where `x` is what you want to rank).  `row_number` does not require this.

Comment: hmm no, I'm not sure... :O

Comment: It doesn't complain when I use `rank`: `by_species <- mutate(by_species, myrank=rank(Sepal.Length))`

Comment: Your post does not use `rank` (the part you are stating is causing problems).  If `rank` is working for you, then does that mean this problem is solved or am I missing something ?

Comment: I think I might be missing something too :) If I use `rank` instead of `row_number` it does not complain but it doesn't do what I want (rank column should be like 1,2,3... 1,2,3.... 1,2,3....)

Comment: @steveb see the edit (and thanks for your patience!)

Comment: Why are you doing this in two parts? Can you make this one full command to arrange and rank?

Comment: I think you're just not using all of your pieces together. `by_species <- iris %>% arrange(Species, Sepal.Length) %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(rank = rank(Sepal.Length, ties.method = "first"))` works for me. You can test this by running `by_species %>% slice(1:3)`.

Comment: Your script produces the desired output as is. I vote to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @brittenb see the edit. Your instructions don't work for me either.

Comment: @Pierre I did it in two parts for no reason, just for debugging.

Comment: @alberto Cut/past the Answer code.  Does this produce an error for you or what you expect ?

Comment: If the code in the answer doesn't work, you may want to restart R and just load `dplyr` (i.e. the minimum number of packages to troubleshoot).  This should reduce the chance of getting functions from a different package unexpectedly.

Comment: @steveb done. No error, but the rank is still global and not by group... my dplyr version is 0.4.3

Comment: If you are doing exactly what is in the answer, but getting different results, this seems more like an issue with your environment (platform?).  If you have access to a different system, perhaps you can try the code in the Answer there too (i.e. is it just the machine you are using). I tried a version of the answer where I used the package name in the call to the function and it sitll works for me: `by_species <- datasets::iris %>% dplyr::arrange(Species, Sepal.Length) %>% dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% dplyr::mutate(rank = base::rank(Sepal.Length, ties.method = "first"))`

Comment: I have seen something similar when loading `plyr` after `dplyr`...

Comment: Bingo! I restarted R as @steveb suggested and it works. I'll edit the question with the reproducible error for the record. Thank you everyone!

Comment: @alberto Good to hear it worked.  Did you by some chance install or update any packages just prior to this restart ?  That can often (but not always) cause issues.

Comment: Between the error and my restart, you mean? Not at all.

Comment: @alberto I stumbled back into this and thought you might want to add something to your edit section.  It seems that you don't need to unload `plyr`, you can load them both (`plyr` and `dplyr`) if you load `plyr` first.

Comment: @steveb loading `plyr` and then `dplyr` it doesn't seem to work in my computer

Comment: I also found that I needed to use ```detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)``` for mine to run properly.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following produces the desired result as was specified.

```
library(dplyr)

by_species <- iris %>% arrange(Species, Sepal.Length) %>%
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    mutate(rank = rank(Sepal.Length, ties.method = "first"))

by_species %>% filter(rank <= 3)
##Source: local data frame [9 x 6]
##Groups: Species [3]
##
##  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species  rank
##         (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)     (fctr) (int)
##1          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa     1
##2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa     2
##3          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa     3
##4          4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor     1
##5          5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor     2
##6          5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 versicolor     3
##7          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica     1
##8          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0  virginica     2
##9          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica     3

by_species %>% slice(1:3)
##Source: local data frame [9 x 6]
##Groups: Species [3]
##
##  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species  rank
##         (dbl)       (dbl)        (dbl)       (dbl)     (fctr) (int)
##1          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa     1
##2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa     2
##3          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa     3
##4          4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor     1
##5          5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor     2
##6          5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 versicolor     3
##7          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica     1
##8          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0  virginica     2
##9          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica     3
```

Comment: This question was asking for a `dplyr` solution so I am putting a `data.table` solution in this comment, as it may be useful.  The following will work using `data.table`: `setDT(iris)[order(Species, Sepal.Length), .SD[1:3], by = Species]`

Answer (score 4):

For future readers, the rank by group variable can be achieved using base R. Per the OP's `iris` data example to rank according to `Sepal.Length`:

```
# ORDER BY SPECIES AND SEPAL.LENGTH
iris <- iris[with(iris, order(Species, Sepal.Length)), ]

# RUN A ROW COUNT FOR RANK BY SPECIES GROUP
iris$rank <- sapply(1:nrow(iris), 
                    function(i) sum(iris[1:i, c('Species')]==iris$Species[i]))

# FILTER DATA FRAME BY TOP 3
iris <- iris[iris$rank <= 3,]
```