# Rank subgroup by group (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967837/rank-variable-by-group-dplyr) addresses how to assign the rank of a row within a group.  I would like to assign the rank of a subgroup to a row within that subgroup.  What I'm really getting at is that I need an abbreviation of the second `group_by` variable that is guaranteed to be unique, and this is the best way I can think of to go about doing that.  Hopefully the desired output below makes this clear enough.

Input dataframe:

```
my_df <- tibble(
  var1 = c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 12)),
  var2 = c(rep("long_string_x", 4), 
           rep("long_string_y", 4),
           rep("long_string_x", 4), 
           rep("long_string_y", 4), 
           rep("long_string_z", 4))
)
```

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   var1  var2          group_rank
   <chr> <chr>              <dbl>
 1 A     long_string_x          1
 2 A     long_string_x          1
 3 A     long_string_x          1
 4 A     long_string_x          1
 5 A     long_string_y          2
 6 A     long_string_y          2
 7 A     long_string_y          2
 8 A     long_string_y          2
 9 B     long_string_x          1
10 B     long_string_x          1
11 B     long_string_x          1
12 B     long_string_x          1
13 B     long_string_y          2
14 B     long_string_y          2
15 B     long_string_y          2
16 B     long_string_y          2
17 B     long_string_z          3
18 B     long_string_z          3
19 B     long_string_z          3
20 B     long_string_z          3
```

How may I assign `group_rank` as above, ideally (but not necessarily) using a tidyverse approach?

Comment: Hello!  Just to clarify what you want: let _G_ = {`var1`, `var2`} be the set of all grouping variables, and let _S_ = {`var2`} be the set of variables that define your subgroup; finally let _T_ = _G_ \ _S_ = {`var1`} be the [relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) of _S_ in _G_.  Do you want to index each subgroup defined by _S_, within each group defined by _T_?  That is: do you want to group by the variables in _T_ and then, within the context of each of those groups, further subgroup the data by _S_ and "rank" those subgroups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use `match` after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
my_df %>% 
   group_by(var1) %>%
   mutate(group_rank = match(var2, unique(var2))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   var1  var2          group_rank
   <chr> <chr>              <int>
 1 A     long_string_x          1
 2 A     long_string_x          1
 3 A     long_string_x          1
 4 A     long_string_x          1
 5 A     long_string_y          2
 6 A     long_string_y          2
 7 A     long_string_y          2
 8 A     long_string_y          2
 9 B     long_string_x          1
10 B     long_string_x          1
11 B     long_string_x          1
12 B     long_string_x          1
13 B     long_string_y          2
14 B     long_string_y          2
15 B     long_string_y          2
16 B     long_string_y          2
17 B     long_string_z          3
18 B     long_string_z          3
19 B     long_string_z          3
20 B     long_string_z          3
```

Comment: This does it!  For where I am in my pipeline, I had guessed the solution would be after `group_by(var1, var2)`. This solution will work; I'll just need to use it earlier in my pipeline than I'd anticipated, before grouping by `var2`.  Thank you.

Comment: @RobCreel then, the grouping will be different because it will be a combination of unique values of 'var1', 'var2'

Answer (score 3):

using the approach to solving the problem of a respected @akrun

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_df <- tibble(
  var1 = c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 12)),
  var2 = c(rep("long_string_x", 4), 
           rep("long_string_y", 4),
           rep("long_string_x", 4), 
           rep("long_string_y", 4), 
           rep("long_string_z", 4))
)

my_df %>% 
  group_by(var1) %>% 
  mutate(res = data.table::rleid(var2))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#> # Groups:   var1 [2]
#>    var1  var2            res
#>    <chr> <chr>         <int>
#>  1 A     long_string_x     1
#>  2 A     long_string_x     1
#>  3 A     long_string_x     1
#>  4 A     long_string_x     1
#>  5 A     long_string_y     2
#>  6 A     long_string_y     2
#>  7 A     long_string_y     2
#>  8 A     long_string_y     2
#>  9 B     long_string_x     1
#> 10 B     long_string_x     1
#> 11 B     long_string_x     1
#> 12 B     long_string_x     1
#> 13 B     long_string_y     2
#> 14 B     long_string_y     2
#> 15 B     long_string_y     2
#> 16 B     long_string_y     2
#> 17 B     long_string_z     3
#> 18 B     long_string_z     3
#> 19 B     long_string_z     3
#> 20 B     long_string_z     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Pleasure to meet you Mr. Saraykin, I would never forget your generous advice on that `t.test` question while ago. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
As Greg pointed out (see comments) that `group_by()` default is `.add = FALSE` the intention was to use `group_by` twice -> then `.add = TRUE` should be added.
like:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df %>% 
    group_by(var1) %>% 
    mutate(group_rank = cur_group_id()) %>% 
    group_by(var2, .add=TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(group_rank = cur_group_id())
```

But in this case as Greg pointed out -> this is enough:

```
my_df %>% group_by(var2) %>% mutate(group_rank = cur_group_id())
```

**First answer:**
We could use `cur_group_id()` twice:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df %>% 
    group_by(var1) %>% 
    mutate(group_rank = cur_group_id()) %>% 
    group_by(var2) %>% 
    mutate(group_rank = cur_group_id())
```

Output:

```
   var1  var2          group_rank
   <chr> <chr>              <int>
 1 A     long_string_x          1
 2 A     long_string_x          1
 3 A     long_string_x          1
 4 A     long_string_x          1
 5 A     long_string_y          2
 6 A     long_string_y          2
 7 A     long_string_y          2
 8 A     long_string_y          2
 9 B     long_string_x          1
10 B     long_string_x          1
11 B     long_string_x          1
12 B     long_string_x          1
13 B     long_string_y          2
14 B     long_string_y          2
15 B     long_string_y          2
16 B     long_string_y          2
17 B     long_string_z          3
18 B     long_string_z          3
19 B     long_string_z          3
20 B     long_string_z          3
```

Comment: Nice use of `cur_group_id()` my friend.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Since `group_by()` defaults to `.add = FALSE`, then `group_by(var2)` will overwrite the existing grouping (by `var1`) and simply leave `my_df` grouped by `var2` **alone**.  Then `mutate(group_rank = cur_group_id())` will simply overwrite the original `group_rank`, with the `cur_group_id()` for the current grouping: by `var2` alone.  Isn't this result exactly the same as `my_df %>% group_by(var2) %>% mutate(group_rank = cur_group_id())`?

Comment: Thank you Greg. This is a good point. I can't remember why I used it this way here. I think the intention was to add `.add=TRUE`. Somehow it worked that way. Anyway the idea was to add a second `group_by`. I will edit my answer! Thanks again!