# Add a grouping variable based on ranked data

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following dataframe:

```
name <- c("Sally", "Dave", "Aaron", "Jane", "Michael")
rank <- c(1,2,1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(name, rank, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'd like to create a grouping variable (event) based on the rank column, as such:

```
event <- c("Hurdles", "Hurdles", "Long Jump", "Long Jump", "Long Jump")
df_desired <- data.frame(name, rank, event, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

There are [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170777/add-a-rank-column-to-a-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967837/rank-variable-by-group-dplyr?noredirect=1&lq=1) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018933/r-data-frame-rank-by-groups-group-by-rank-with-package-dplyr?noredirect=1&lq=1) of going the other way (making a ranking variable based on a group) but I can't seem to find one doing what I'd like.

It's possible to use `filter`, `full_join` and then `fill` as shown below, but is there a simpler way?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number())

df_1 <- df %>% 
  filter(rank == 1)
df_1$event <- c("Hurdles", "Long Jump")

df %>% 
  filter(rank != 1) %>% 
  mutate(event = as.character(NA)) %>% 
  full_join(df_1, by = c("order", "name", "rank", "event")) %>% 
  arrange(order) %>% 
  fill(event) %>%
  select(-order)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` to create the index

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(event = c("Hurdles", "Long Jump")[cumsum(rank == 1)])
#      name rank     event
#1   Sally    1   Hurdles
#2    Dave    2   Hurdles
#3   Aaron    1 Long Jump
#4    Jane    2 Long Jump
#5 Michael    3 Long Jump
```

---

Or in `base R` (just in case)

```
df$event <- c("Hurdles", "Long Jump")[cumsum(df$rank == 1)])
```