# R: split data based on a factor, add a ranking column and extract

Tags: r

I still haven't been able to know how we can access different elements of a split data. Here is my problem:
I have a data set, that I want to split based on a column (State). I want to have a ranking column added to my data for each subset. This is part of a function I'm writing. 
My data set has 2 columns, Hospital, State, Outcome. For each state, I want to add a 'Rank' column that ranks the data based on Outcome; the lowest Outcome will be ranked 1 and the highest outcome will be ranked the last.

How can I use split, sapply/lapply to do this? Is there a better way, like using "arrange"? 
My main problem is that when I use either of these methods, I do not know how to access each element of the split or arranged data. 
Here's how my data set looks like: 
Hospital State Outcome. The row lines are not important here.

```
                           Hospital State Outcome 
 1 SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    AL    14.3
 2    MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH    AL    18.5
 3   ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    TX    18.1
 7                ST VINCENT'S EAST    TX    17.7
 8   DEKALB REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AL    18.0
 9    SHELBY BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER    AL    15.9
```

The desired outcome would be

```
                           Hospital State Outcome Rank
 1 SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    AL    14.3    1
 2 SHELBY BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER       AL    15.9    2
 3 DEKALB REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER      AL    18.0    3               
 4 MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH       AL    18.5    4 
 5 ST VINCENT'S EAST                   TX    17.7    1 
 6 ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL      TX    18.1    2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I don't know how to access". There are numerous of ways to subset and access the rows and columns of a data frame (I assume you are reading this into a data frame). Maybe if you gave an example of what you would expect to see.

Comment: Maybe you are looking to summarize the data by state, etc? Then you want to look to the ddply package or something similar.

Comment: Right. That was just a sample of my data and it happened to be all in one state. I changed this in my post so that you would have a better idea what it is.

Comment: @MikeWise  what I mean is, when I split a data set based on state in this example, and call it s, s[1] will show me all the lines related to the first "State". I do not know how to extract different rows or even different columns of a row in each dataset. So if s[1] has 50 lines from NY and s[2] has 32 rows from WY, I do not know how to access individual rows in each subset, let's say row i in s[1].

Comment: @AsiehHarati I think Mike's question about "accessing" is based on the vagueness of what you're saying. `split` is an R function and we don't know if you're referring to it or just some sort of subsetting... if `s=split(DF,DF$state)`, you would refer to `s[[1]]` not `s[1]`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dplyr` package provides a very elegant solution for this type of problem. I'm using the `mtcars` data as an example:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(rank = row_number(mpg))
```

Answer (score 3):

The OP's example is hard to read into R because of all the spaces in the string variable.

Here's a simpler example:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(id=rep(1:2,sample(5,2))); DF$v <- runif(nrow(DF))*100
#   id        v
# 1  A 57.28534
# 2  A 90.82078
# 3  B 20.16819
# 4  B 89.83897
# 5  B 94.46753
# 6  B 66.07978
# 7  B 62.91140
```

Here's a solution without using any packages:

```
DF$r <- ave(DF$v,DF$id,FUN=rank)
#   id        v r
# 1  A 57.28534 1
# 2  A 90.82078 2
# 3  B 20.16819 1
# 4  B 89.83897 4
# 5  B 94.46753 5
# 6  B 66.07978 3
# 7  B 62.91140 2
```

Finally, to order by ranking within state:

```
DF[order(DF$id,DF$r),]
#   id        v r
# 1  A 57.28534 1
# 2  A 90.82078 2
# 3  B 20.16819 1
# 7  B 62.91140 2
# 6  B 66.07978 3
# 4  B 89.83897 4
# 5  B 94.46753 5
```

If you have ties in the column you're ranking, read the documentation for `rank` and decide how you want the ties treated. The `dplyr` and `data.table` packages (mentioned in the other answers) also have nice functionality for dealing with ties, like the notion of a "[dense rank](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27923279/1191259)."

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, myrank := rank(Outcome), by = State]
dat[,.SD[order(myrank)], by=State]

#      State                         Hospital Outcome myrank
#1:    AL SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    14.3      1
#2:    AL    SHELBY BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER    15.9      2
#3:    AL   DEKALB REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    18.0      3
#4:    AL    MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH    18.5      4
#5:    TX                  ST VINCENT EAST    17.7      1
#6:    TX   ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    18.1      2
```

Or using `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(State), function(x){x$myrank = rank(x$Outcome); x[order(x$myrank),]})

#                          Hospital State Outcome myrank
#1 SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    AL    14.3      1
#2    SHELBY BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER    AL    15.9      2
#3   DEKALB REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AL    18.0      3
#4    MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH    AL    18.5      4
#5                  ST VINCENT EAST    TX    17.7      1
#6   ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    TX    18.1      2
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It works now. But can you tell me what does [,.SD mean? I could not find it in help.
Also, what is the := operator?

Comment: @AsiehHarati `.SD` stands for the subset of `data.table`

Comment: @AsiehHarati `:=` is called as `set`, here setting a new column as `myrank`

Comment: Also, now I cannot use data[1][3] for instance to access the first row and the 3rd column element of my dataframe. it gave me the right one before using these 2 lines but now it doesn't, although dim gives the right dimensions.

Comment: It doesn't give me the right element :(
It gives me 3. Neither of the following gives me the right element:
completecase[1,][,3]
completecase[1,3]
completecase[1][3]

Comment: @AsiehHarati Accessing rows and columns with `[` is different with a data.table. Columns have to be accessed like `DT[,2,with=FALSE]`. To use this package, one must learn a little bit of new syntax. Help pages are here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: @Veerndra Gadekar,  Thank you very much for your help. the ddply works just fine. :)

Comment: @AsiehHarati you may want to use `tie.method` something like this `rank(x$Outcome, ties.method = "first")` if you find ties in the rank, but again there are different `tie.methods`, consider to check `?rank` to select the most appropriate for your case

Answer (score 1):

You can use `by`:

```
do.call(
    rbind, 
    by(d, list(State = d$State), function(x) { x$Rank <- order(x$Outcome); x[order(x$Rank), ] }))
```

where `d` is your raw data.